# PHP & PDO - is there any method to make 'safe' persistent connections?

Tags: php, pdo, connection, persistent

I know (through reading on countless posts here on SO and other sites) persistent connections are not something very loved among the vast majority of developers (if the script terminates abruptly, the connection doesn't get closed, you could end leaving some tables locked, etc.) but is it really THAT bad?

On my development machine (T3400 dual-core CPU, 4 gigabytes of RAM and a 5400RPM hard disk), page loading times are **very different** depending on whether I'm using persistent or non-persistent connections. Very different as in 2.09s for non-persistent vs. (roughly) 68ms for a persistent connection. Here are two sample screenshots for you to see: [non-persistent](http://i46.tinypic.com/1125v8z.png) vs. [persistent](http://i49.tinypic.com/v65380.png).

I understand the risks of a persistent connection (I don't really use them on a daily basis, although I find the concept interesting and I would like to explore it), but isn't there any method to detect non-closed connections?

Like, for example, an equivalent to mysqli's `change_user` but for PDO, or some kind of PHP script the server runs as a cron job once every X seconds to check for left-overs and, subsequently, close them? I was reading about `register_shutdown_function` but, if I understood it correctly, it gets called once the script finishes so, in practice, that probably means it would end closing my persistent connections anyway each time the script finishes. Or am I wrong?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention my software stack, for accuracy purposes, so let me make amend of that. My current stack is composed of the following elements: `Windows 7 (x86) SP1` as the OS, `Apache 2.4.3`, `PHP 5.4.9` (I always work with the latest versions) and `MySQL 5.5.28`. Running the stack as `localhost` (I'm probably migrating it to a dedicated machine but, for now, it stays like this).

Comment: I find it odd that on a local machine the cost of establishing a MySQL connection would be 2 seconds. Something is fishy here, are you sure it's the persistent vs non-persistent that is causing such a drastic change in performance? Using persistent connection might not be the cure, the problem would still persist and I'd hunt the culprit rather than rectifying the issue using something potentially dangerous.

Comment: Sorry, like I just commented on @hek2mgl's answer, I'm creating two persistent connections. One is for the core application database (where I want to store clients billing information and a couple of things) and one for the client database (where all the application modules will store their data, like quotations, orders, invoices, delivery notes and so on). My actual code test looks like `$sql['core'] = $database->addConnection("core"); $sql['client'] = $database->addConnection("client");`. Hence those two seconds. It's one second per connection.

Comment: 1 second is still too much. A db connection shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds on a machine that's not under load and has sufficient RAM available.

Comment: Even for a non-persistent connection?

Comment: Yes, it's way too much. It takes literally below 10ms to establish a db connection on a regular machine that's nowhere near as good as yours. It might not be MySQL or PDO that's the culprit here. Also, since you're saving sensitive financial data - just forget about persistent connections, those two should never be used in the same sentence, let alone thought.

Comment: I see... I'll try moving the whole codebase to a virtual machine with VirtualBox for now and running a test there to see if Windows is the culprit. About the 'don't mix these'... thanks for the advice. Like I stated in my original comment, I don't really use them, but they looked like a possible solution to my connection speed problems. I'll look into it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Indeed! It was Windows... I just installed a fresh virtual machine with Ubuntu server 12.10, PHP 5.4.6 (what came with the official package repository), MySQL 5.5.28 and Apache 2.2 (I need to re-test with 2.4 but so far, so good) and... voilá! Non-persistent connection in (roughly) 15-22ms (and I suspect it's due to the latency the VM imposes, or maybe the it's the VM itself). Definitely, BIG kudos for the hint. I owe you a beer ;)

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll take that beer one day :)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid that the connection will be closed on every shutdown you can check `error_get_last()` in your shutdown function.

Note that `error_get_last()` will also return 'errors' like E_NOTICE etc. This should be filtered out depending on your needs.

```php
<?php

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

function shutdown() {

    static $ignore = array (
        E_STRICT,
        E_NOTICE,
        E_USER_NOTICE,
        E_DEPRECATED,
        E_USER_DEPRECATED, // ...
    );

    $error = error_get_last();
    // if no error has been queued or it should be ignored ...
    if(is_null($error) || in_array($error['type'], $ignore)) {
        return; // do nothing
    }

    // here comes your connection close code
    connection_close($your_connection);
}
```

But this is a really hacky solution with a lots of limitations [see www.php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

I'm wondering because of the ~2sec it takes to serve the page when using non permanent connections. Does it really mean that establishing a connection to your database server takes ~2sec? If so I would take care on this as it seems very long. What database server do you use? Is the database server located on a different machine?

Comment: Sorry, I needed to be a bit more specific. Those 2 seconds comes from me calling my `addConnection` method twice (I was creating two persistent connections), so it's ~1 second per connection.

Comment: Ok, but I confirm with N.B.'s comment above. It should take not more than ~10ms to establish a connection on your hardware.

Comment: It was a combination between Windows having an extremely crappy address resolution (specifying 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost' mitigated my slowness problem) and using a real solution: going Linux. Now the connection times go between 11 and 21ms. Now THAT is normal :P